# Hightlight differences between items in table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add to a HTML table a feature that highlights all those values that, compared to others, are different. Comparison is made row by row.

With great effort I managed to achieve the following JQuery/Javascrit code. I'm pretty sure this is **not** an efficient/elegant/fast way to do it but it's the only way I work it out.

The HTML table is quite big and complex so it's hard to publish it here.

**The issue** I'm encountering is that the script works fine out of a loop, but **it hangs if I put it inside a FOR - LOOP** and I don't understand why.

```
var numRows = $('.ctable tbody tr').length, numCols = $('.ctable tbody tr:first th').length, v, undefined;
var values = new Array(numRows);
var noDuplicates = new Array(numCols);
var result = new Array(numCols);


for (i = 1; i = numRows; i++) {

    // Get a row and copy into an array the values of each VISIBLE cell
    $(".ctable tbody tr:eq(" + i + ") td.values:visible").each(function(){
         v = $(this).text();
         values.push(v.trim());
    });

    // Remove from the array the 'undefined' values
    values = values.filter(function(item){
        return item !== undefined;
    });

    // Push into new array duplicate values
    noDuplicates = return_duplicates(values);

   // Compare the two arrays and get the differences (uses underscore.js)
   result = _.difference(values, noDuplicates);

   // This is a 'highlight' plugin and you may pass to it an array
   $(".ctable tbody tr:eq(" + i + ") td.values:visible").highlight(values);
}

function return_duplicates(arr) {
    var len=arr.length, out=[], counts={};
    for (var i=0;i<len;i++) {
         var item = arr[i];
         counts[item] = counts[item] >= 1 ? counts[item] + 1 : 1;
    }
    for (var item in counts) {
        if(counts[item] > 1)
        out.push(item);
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Can you give the value of numRows here? Have you tried using js debugger for loop iteration?

Comment: Can you give us the for loop hanging up the script?

Comment: I tested your `return_dublicates` method and I got it working. I think your code looks alright. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/Lbcprygt/

Comment: I think it would be interesting to know what the array looks like after the filter call and before it is passed to return_dublicates method.

Comment: `numRows = 44` but the script hangs even if I set the loop as `for (i=1; i=1; i++) {}` or `for (i=1; i=3; i++) {}` for example. The script hangs even if I leave only the first three lines of code (the first JQuery selector) and comment all the others. If I leave running only the first three lines Firefox debugger stops highlighting something inside jquery.js. If I leave running the first three lines AND the highlight plugin, the debugger stops on the plugin. If I leave the code as it is, the debugger stops where I remove the 'undefined' values. Sorry I can't be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
for (i = 1; i < numRows; i++) {
```

instead of

```
for (i = 1; i = numRows; i++) {
```